# How to create a button like that in Android

Tags: android

Is there a simple way to create a button that looks more or less like that in Android, using margins or something similar ? (I do not whant to create Bitmaps)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to create a button that looks more or less like that in andorid

Yes create an image resource (png file perhaps) that looks like that and set it as the background of the Button.

> (I do not whant to create Bitmaps)

I am not entirely certain what you mean by not wanting to create bitmaps. But if you mean that you don't want to use an actual image file, then it might help if you could explain why you don't want to. But If this is the case no, there is not "a simple way" to do it. You'd have to manually create xml shape objects that make the grey 'L' shape and then perhaps use some custom font to create the letters. Then you'd have to adjust padding/margins until it lined up how you want (keeping in mind it may look different on different devices)

Comment: Maybe he wants a dynamic button, so that he can change the text in future

Comment: I think A custom font would be the easiest way to achieve that if so.

Comment: In fact in my case I will generate several button with different texts, and sorry for not beeing clear on that, but the font in not important, I want the text and the border only.

Comment: @Paolo in that case personally I would use a 9.patch png to make the border corner show up.